# java proxy settings - eclipse

Tags: java, url, proxy

When I try to read an url from eclipse, it gives "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect" error. I assume that it is cause of proxy settings of eclipse is not same my browser.

I am coding from my company computer, so please let me know how I can make it same as my browser.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a simple google search.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want for example to load plugins from eclipse IDE or you want to write java code that can make http requests through proxy server?

Comment: When I look at my connection settings from Explorer - use automatic configuration script box is checked and there is a value like "http://wgate.test.entp.tgc:8080/wpad.dat". Proxy server box is not checked. When I try to read google.com line by line, eclipse gives me connection time out error. My request is how I can configure eclipse to be able to open the page @DmitryShebeko

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure proxy setting in eclipse too.

Go to Window --> Preference  in you eclipse,

under General menu, you could find Network connections, where you can configure proxy settings.

Comment: When I look at my connection settings from Explorer - use automatic configuration script box is checked and there is a value like "wgate.test.entp.tgc:8080/wpad.dat";. Proxy server box is not checked. When I try to read google.com line by line, eclipse gives me connection time out error. My request is how I can configure eclipse to be able to open the page

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to add the wpad file as in modern Browsers (mozilla for example) but if you have this file you can search your prox name and the port and add it manually in eclipse settings like this:
[Eclipse proxy settings](https://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/)

you can use **crt+F** to find the proxy url in wpad file